# JAXWS / JAXB doesn't bind attributes of references Object from seperate jar

Tags: web-services, jaxb, xsd, jax-ws, marshalling

**Problem:**

When JAXB unmarshalls the xml into the object tree, the attributes of objects from a seperate jar (and schema) are not set and remain null.

See the code below. On unmarshalling, the attributes of the MeldingType class remain NULL, even though the SOAP message has filled the 'code' and 'melding' child-elemens in the 'meldingen' elements.

If I create a 'local' version of MeldingType in the .war and also place the .xsd definition of MeldingType in the out.xsd, everything works perfectly. :(

How can I work with a seperate jar, so that I can share common JAXB objects from common .xsd's?

**Situation**

I have a war and a jar file.

- The .war contains a class 'RequestType', package-info, out.xsd and out.wsdl.
- The .jar contains a class 'MeldingType', package-info, and schema.xsd

**WAR FILE**

Package info:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://schemas.xxx.nl/schema/out/v0010", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package nl.xxx.out.web.model;
```

RequestType

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "XbOutRequestType", propOrder = {
    "kenmerk",
    "meldingen"
})
public class XbOutRequestType {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String kenmerk;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected List<MeldingType> meldingen = new ArrayList<MeldingType>();

    public String getKenmerk() {
        return this.kenmerk;
    }

    public List<MeldingType> getMeldingen() {
        return this.meldingen;
    }
}
```

out.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:ref="http://schemas.xxx.nl/schema/v0010"
    targetNamespace="http://schemas.xxx.nl/out/v0010"
        xmlns="http://schemas.xxx.nl/out/v0010"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"> 

    <xsd:element name="request" type="RequestType"/>

    <xsd:element name="respomse" type="ResponseType"/>

    <xsd:complexType name="RequestType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="kenmerk" type="ref:kenmerkType" minOccurs="1"/>            
            <xsd:element name="meldingen" type="ref:MeldingType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="XbOutResponseType"/>        

</xsd:schema>
```

out.wsdl

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                  xmlns:tns="http://schemas.xxx.nl/wsdl/out/v0010"
                  xmlns:typ="http://schemas.xxx.nl/schema/out/v0010"
                  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  name="XbRender" targetNamespace="http://schemas.xxx.nl/wsdl/out/v0010">

    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://schemas.xxx.nl/wsdl/out/v0010"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xxx.nl/schema/out/v0010"     schemaLocation="out.xsd" />
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>

    <wsdl:message name="request">
        <wsdl:part name="body" element="typ:request" />
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:message name="response">
        <wsdl:part name="body" element="typ:response" />
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:portType name="portType">
        <wsdl:operation name="execute">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:request" />
            <wsdl:output message="tns:response" />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>

    <wsdl:binding name="soapBinding" type="tns:portType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="execute">
            <soap:operation soapAction="execute"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="service">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:soapBinding" name="soapBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:9080/dummy" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

**JAR**

Package info:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://schemas.xxx.nl/schema/v0010")
package nl.xxx.schema.jaxb.model;
```

MeldingType

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "MeldingType", propOrder = {
    "code",
    "melding"
})
public class MeldingType {

@XmlElement(required = true)
private String code;

@XmlElement(required = true)
private String melding;

public MeldingType() {
}

public MeldingType(final String code, final String melding) {
    this.code = code;
    this.melding = melding;
}

    public String getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }

    public String getMelding() {
        return this.melding;
    }

    public void setCode(final String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public void setMelding(final String melding) {
        this.melding = melding;
    }
}
```

schema.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="http://schemas.xxx.nl/schema/v0010"
            xmlns="http://schemas.xxx.nl/schema/v0010"
                elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:simpleType name="kenmerkType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="12" />
            <xsd:maxLength value="32" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:complexType name="MeldingType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="code" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="melding" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Do you have an `ObjectFactory` defined?